# Joining JS array with HTML table

Tags: javascript, html

I created a table with HTML and I need to join that table with an array from JS:

```js
var array = [
  ["A4", "Audi", "2015", "1234"],
  ["A3", "Audi", "2011", "1542"],
  ["335i", "BMW", "2012", "9874"],
  ["440d", "BMW", "2015", "1975"],
  ["Civic", "Honda", "2002", "6574"],
]
console.log(array)

table = document.getElementById("myTable");
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  // create a new row
  var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);
  for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
    // create a new cell
    var cell = newRow.insertCell(j);

    // add value to the cell
    cell.innerHTML = array[i][j];
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <caption id=a><b>Automobiliai</caption></b>
    <tr>
      <th>Modelis</th>
      <th>Gamintojas</th>
      <th>Metai</th>
      <th>Variklio Numeris</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But I get the error in console: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertRow')"
What is wrong there?

Comment: Declare the table variable using `var = table` or `let = table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by adding the following line to my JS file:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () { });
```

Comment: That wouldn't have been nessecary if you placed the script @ the bottom of the document, right before the closing `</body>`-tag

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by looping through the country list and creating an HTML string. Then you can put that inside the tbody using a class or id selector. Here is an example

```js
var country = ["Norway", "Sweden", "Denmark"];
    var capital = ["Oslo", "Stockholm" , "Copenhagen"]

    var bodyString = '';
    $.each(country, function(index, ctry) {
        bodyString += ('<tr><td>'+ctry+'</td><td>'+capital[index]+'</td></tr>');
    });
    $('.countriesTable tbody').html(bodyString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

  <table class="countriesTable">
      <thead>
          <tr><th>Country</th><th>Capital</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      
      </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code works. Here is an alternative approach, using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create the rows and [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to append the rows.

```js
document.querySelector(`#myTable`).insertAdjacentHTML(
  `beforeEnd`, [
    ["A4", "Audi", "2015", "1234"],
    ["A3", "Audi", "2011", "1542"],
    ["335i", "BMW", "2012", "9874"],
    ["440d", "BMW", "2015", "1975"],
    ["Civic", "Honda", "2002", "6574"],
  ].reduce( (acc, [Modelis, Gamintojas, Metai, VariklioNumeris]) =>
    `${acc}<tr><td>${Modelis}</td><td>${Gamintojas}</td><td>${
        Metai}</td><td>${VariklioNumeris}</td></tr>`, ``)
);
```

```css
#myTable th:nth-child(n+3):nth-child(-n+4),
#myTable td:nth-child(n+3):nth-child(-n+4) {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <caption id=a><b>Automobiliai</caption></b>
    <tr>
      <th>Modelis</th>
      <th>Gamintojas</th>
      <th>Metai</th>
      <th>Variklio Numeris</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: I think, I found your problem, actually your script is loading before html]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <table id="myTable">
      <caption id=a><b>Automobiliai</caption></b>
      <tr>
        <th>Modelis</th>
        <th>Gamintojas</th>
        <th>Metai</th>
        <th>Variklio Numeris</th>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var array = [
        ["A4", "Audi", "2015", "1234"],
        ["A3", "Audi", "2011", "1542"],
        ["335i", "BMW", "2012", "9874"],
        ["440d", "BMW", "2015", "1975"],
        ["Civic", "Honda", "2002", "6574"],
        ["A4", "Audi", "2015", "1234"],
        ["A3", "Audi", "2011", "1542"],
        ["335i", "BMW", "2012", "9874"],
        ["440d", "BMW", "2015", "1975"],
        ["Civic", "Honda", "2002", "6574"],
        ]
        console.log(array)

        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
        // create a new row
        var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);
        for(var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
        {
        // create a new cell
        var cell = newRow.insertCell(j);

        // add value to the cell
        cell.innerHTML = array[i][j];
        }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think, I found your problem, actually your script is loading before looping elements

Comment: Thank you for putting my on the right path. Fixed the problem by adding
"document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () { }); to my JS file

Comment: Welcome sir, But I don't know why I received negative vote because my answer was correct according to further situation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `table` variable as `var table =`  or `let table =`  and you can more optimize your code with `map()` method like below snippet.

**Helpful Link:**
`Variables:` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Variables

`map() method:` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```js
var array = [
    ["A4", "Audi", "2015", "1234"],
    ["A3", "Audi", "2011", "1542"],
    ["335i", "BMW", "2012", "9874"],
    ["440d", "BMW", "2015", "1975"],
    ["Civic", "Honda", "2002", "6574"],
]
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
array.map((v,i)=>{
    var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);
    array[i].map((val,j)=> {
       var cell = newRow.insertCell(j);
       cell.innerHTML = array[i][j];
    })
});
```

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td,
table th{
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 7px;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
    <caption id="a"><strong>Automobiliai</strong></caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Modelis</th>
        <th>Gamintojas</th>
        <th>Metai</th>
        <th>Variklio Numeris</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why would you (ab)use `map` for this?

Comment: @KooiInc for fast rendering and optimize code like: `for loop is for executing the same block of code for a fixed number of times, the map also does that but in a single line of code.`

Comment: [Please read](https://dev.to/catchmareck/stop-abusing-map-51mj). `forEach` or `reduce` would've been more appropriate. If you need performance (say, a few million rows) it's better to use a classic loop.

Comment: @KooiInc thanks for sharing article link. Next time I will use `.forEach()` method instead of `.map()`

Comment: Just for fun: [here is](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-qtmu8g?file=index.js) a more generic `reduce/map`-solution

Comment: @KooiInc Wow super advance level example thanks for sharing so I learn a lot from above link.

Answer (score -1):

When I add your code to a [jsfiddle](http://%20https://jsfiddle.net/ypg0u53b/1/), it works

So what's the problem exactly?

Maybe you're loading your JS before your table loads, that would explain why it works on JS fiddle, because there it loads the JS on the right time.

Comment: That's really strange, it works on jsfiddle, but it doesn't work on my browser

Comment: @Dimensijus maybe you're loading your JS before your table loads, that would explain why it works on JS fiddle, because there it loads the JS on the right time.

Comment: Thought the same, but that's not the case right there. I declared my JS file at the very beginning of my html file, but still :/